# MultiIndex Pandas DataFrame to Spark DataFrame & Missing Indexes

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, multi-index

Having a MultiIndex Pandas DataFrame, how one can convert it to an Spark DataFrame without losing the indexes. This can be easily tested using a toy example:

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
          ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=arrays)
df_spark = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df)
```

misses all indexes. Is there something else I need to take care of in order to preserve the indexes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spark SQL has no concept of index, so if you want to preserve it, you have to reset or assign it to a column first:

```py
df_spark = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.reset_index(drop=False))
```

This will create a `DataFrame` with an additional column for each field in the index:

```py
df_spark.printSchema()
```

```
root
 |-- level_0: string (nullable = true)
 |-- level_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- 0: double (nullable = true)
 |-- 1: double (nullable = true)
 |-- 2: double (nullable = true)
 |-- 3: double (nullable = true)
```

You can also use `inplace` to avoid additional memory overhead:

```
df.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
df_spark = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df)
```